# Adding an if query to wordpress meta value doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a code where i count the meta values but only want to show the "a href" if there is any meta value but it won't work:

```
<?php $meta = (get_posts(array('meta_key' => 'city', 'meta_value' => 'Seelbach', true))); ?>
<?php if ( $meta == '') { 
echo "1111111111111111111";
} else {                                
echo "000000000000";
} ?>
```

the

```
if ($meta == '')
```

just gets ignored ... any idea?

Comment: Which is it?  `$meta == ''` or `$meta == ' '`?  One of them is an empty string, the other is a single space

Comment: And basic debugging is called for.  `var_dump($meta);` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: i think need $meta = ''  because i want to check if the meta is empty.

Comment: I understand that. Your code is inconsistent though.  You are checking for a single space in `if ($meta == ' ')`, _not_ for an empty string.  [According to the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Return_Value), `get_posts()` always returns an array.  In PHP, an empty array is not equal to an empty string.  Try `if (empty($meta))`  (see [the type comparison tables](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for reference

Comment: okay an empty array is no empty string, thanks that was the info i needed!! big THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Wordpress `get_posts()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Return_Value), its return value is an `array()`.  By PHP's  [rules for equality between types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), an empty array is not equal to an empty string.

```
var_dump([] == '');
// bool(false)
```

Instead, test that the returned array is `empty()`.

```
if (empty($meta)) {
  // do the empty action
} else {
  // do the populated action
}
```